# How many LaTeX classes and packages are there (say, on CTAN)?

Tags: packages, document-classes, ctan

Well, the question is pretty self-explanatory.  (I'm writing a short tutorial on LaTeX, and wanted some trivia;)).

Comment: More than there are stars in the sky...

Comment: last year > 3100 packages/classes/...

Comment: Today's count (2018-09-07): packages 4239, classes 473.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### TeX Live

TeX Live 2012 (2012-09-19)

```bash
$ egrep -c '\.sty$' ls-R
3381
$ egrep -c '\.cls$' ls-R
448
$ egrep -c '\.(sty|cls)$' texmf-dist/ls-R
3829
```

Windows has `findstr`, but it has some limitations. For example, it cannot detect Unix line ends or the end of the last line, if the file does not end with a end-of-line marker.

The equivalent for `wc -l` is `find /c /v ""`, see [What is the Windows equivalent of “wc -l”?](https://superuser.com/q/959036).

```batch
> findstr /c:.sty ls-R | find /c /v ""
> findstr /c:.cls ls-R | find /c /v ""
> findstr /c:.sty /c:.cls ls-R | find /c /v ""
```

Different method:

```bash
$ find texmf-dist/tex/latex \( -name \*.sty -or -name \*.cls \) | wc -l
3148
$ find texmf-dist/tex/generic \( -name \*.sty -or -name \*.cls \) | wc -l
191
$ find texmf-dist/tex \( -name \*.sty -or -name \*.cls \) | wc -l
3500
```

Windows:

```batch
> (cd texmf-dist\tex\latex && dir /s /b *.sty *.cls | find /c /v "")
> (cd texmf-dist\tex\generic && dir /s /b *.sty *.cls | find /c /v "")
> (cd texmf-dist\tex\tex && dir /s /b *.sty *.cls | find /c /v "")
```

But:

- False positives: `.sty`/`.cls` files that are not LaTeX packages or classes.
- There are packages that divide their work on smaller units (modules in `tikz`, …) that are formally LaTeX packages.
- TeX Live only contains a subset of free packages and classes.

### TeX Catalogue

2012-09-19

```bash
$ find catalogue/entries/ -exec grep -l '/macros/latex' {} \; | wc -l
2154
```

Windows:

```batch
> dir /s /b catalogue\entries | findstr /m /f:/ /c:/macros/latex | find /c /v ""
```

But:

- Not all package in CTAN are in the Catalogue.
- There are packages outside `CTAN:macros/latex/` (e.g. `pgf`) or packages that can
  be used in different formats.
- One Catalogue entry might contain several packages and classes.
- False positives: Driver files and other stuff (e.g. `pdftex-def`).

Comment: Can you provide windows version of these commands with `FINDSTR` in cmd?

Comment: @Qaher See updated answer. Because of the limitation of `findstr`, the strings `.sty` and `.cls` are also be found inside a file name.

Answer (score 4):

On a full MiKTeX installation:

```
$ find . | grep '\.sty' | wc -l
3498
$ find . | grep '\.cls' | wc -l
349
```

So about 3500 style files and about 350 class files.

Comment: That are a lot more style files than i thought, based on the number of packages.

Comment: Why not just `find . -name \*.sty | wc -l`?  (Or even `find . -name \*.sty -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 basename | sort | uniq | wc -l`, just in case;)?)  Anyway, thanks; I didn't do this myself only because I do not have a full TeXlive installation (and I don't want/have time to).

Answer (score 3):

At least the MiKTeX Package Manager has 2371 packages at the moment.

Comment: This is probably a good estimate, though obviously some of these either (a) provide more than one package/class or (b) provide no LaTeX packages/classes.

Comment: @mbork Or are obsolete.