# How many packages do MiKTeX and TeX Live contain?

Tags: texlive, miktex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many LaTeX classes and packages are there (say, on CTAN)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73247/how-many-latex-classes-and-packages-are-there-say-on-ctan)

Where can I find the total package count for TeX Live 2012 and MiKTeX 2.9?

Comment: another related thread [How to print the list of packages installed on TeX Live to a file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56009/15717)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit what you mean by a package

```
$ tlmgr show | wc -l 
4955
```

so tlmgr knows almost 5000 packages, but some of these are system-specific versions of binary packages. In my TL2012 installation I have this many packages installed.

```
$ tlmgr show | grep "^i" |wc -l 
2491
```

Comment: Does this also count packages installed in the personal tree?

Comment: No I guess not, I'm not  sure "package" means anything in this context other then the units installed by the texlive manager. It's not really related to "latex package" ie a file with .sty extension that you can of course just install by dropping in to a local directory.

Answer (score 4):

For MiKTeX, you can find it here:

[miktex page](http://miktex.org/)

[image]

I have no idea for TeX Live as I don't use it `:-(`

Comment: But you should add, that there is a basic MiKTeX installer with a limited amount of packages.

Comment: @Speravir there is also a [full miktex installer](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/setup/setup-2.9.4503.exe) on the `Other Downloads` section of [Miktex download page](http://miktex.org/download)

Comment: @texenthusiast Yes, I know. Sorry, that I wrote misinterpretively.